# How can i change symbol in tooltips on a chart? HIGCHARTS

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I have a round symbol in tolltip now, I need a square and I need change a size.

Thank you

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/n3h2totc/][2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change everything inside tooltip by https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function(tooltip) {
      return `<span style="color:${this.point.color}; font-size: 16px">■</span> ${this.series.name}: <b>${this.point.y}</b><br/>`
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }]
})
```